# Facebook chat application using facebook-java-api

Tags: java, facebook

I am trying to develop a **desktop chat application** using [facebook-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/).But someone told me that it don't work anymore as it was abandoned 2 years back.
[Facebook Developer Doc](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/) says it still supports Chat API using XMPP protocol.Can someone tell me how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

facebook-java-api has been abandoned, and I think [RestFB](http://restfb.com/) is now the de facto Java client for Graph, FQL & "legacy REST" apis.  But for a desktop chat application you'll need to use a Java XMPP client such as [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) - facebook-java-api never supported XMPP.